# browserslists causing npm build problems/errors

Tags: javascript, json

My create-react-app is failing to build, giving this error:

```
./src/index.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I've gone through my package-lock.json and updated all packages that have dependencies on browserslist, but some of them do not update to above v3 which I think is where the problems lie, they are:

-autoprefixer
-babel-preset-env
-babel-preset-react-app
-postcss-merge-rules

Can I just remove these packages - although other packages depend on them, i'm kind of stuck with what to do, the app runs fine but doesnt build so surely it wont work on a dev server?

my package.json is:

```
   {
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@shopify/polaris": "latest",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.5.2",
    "caniuse-api": "^3.0.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.3",
    "postcss-merge-rules": "^4.0.3",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router": "latest",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "serve": "^10.1.2",
    "start": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that you went through your package-lock and updated the versions, were you sure to run `npm install` again after doing so?

You could try running `npm update` to see if that resolves your problem.

If that still doesn't resolve the issue, you can run `npm ls` to list all the packages and their dependancies to try and find the package that has a dependancy for a previous version of BrowserList, check the version of that package to check if you can update it and if you can't then you may need to get in touch with the owner of the package

Comment: I dont have time to get in touch with the owner with the package really, is there a workaround? can I just delete the package?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app

Comment: It would depend on which package it is and how important it is to you, the first step would be to identify the offending package and then you can figure out if it's required

Comment: in the error it doesnt tell me which package is the offending one unfortunately haha!

Comment: it won't that's why unfortunatley you may need to run `npm ls` which will bring back a massive list of all your packages, when you run this you could do `npm ls > output.txt` which will put the results of the npm ls into a text file for you. So you can then open it and search the file for BrowserList

Comment: One thing ive noticed is that in my package-lock.json my browserslist version is still low, 2.11.3, but in my package.json its upgraded to v4+, this is where the error partly comes from, as it says '2.11.3' is that okay? for the discrepency between the two?

Comment: browserlist may appear multiple times in your package.lock as dependancies of other packages, where you see the one which has the version 2.11.3, which package is this being pulled in for? That will be the offending package that you may need to update

Comment: its actually react-scripts itself!

Comment: im using v 1.1.5

Comment: the latest version is 2.1.8, try updating to that with `npm install react-scripts` and fingers crossed that'll fix it for you

Comment: I've got some crap about "babel-loader": "8.0.5" being detected as 8.0.4... this has happened before too!!!

Comment: I removed node_modules and package-lock.json few times etc

Comment: try to remove just the babel-loader folder from the node_modules directory and then run `npm i babel-loader@8.0.5` see if this resolves it, it might be that this then knocks onto another package giving you trouble where you should then do the same until there are no issues

Comment: Man problems like this make me want to get pen to paper, finger to button and come up with a NEW solution, something better, easier to manage, easier to diagnose problems with... a new node.js